# Can't open file /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim

Tags: vim

Whenever I use vim command, I get this error:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/boss/.vimrc:
line    6:
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Whenever I try to do an `ls` command:

```
ls: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/: No such file or directory
```

I found that the directory: `/usr/share/vim/vim73/` doesn't exist!
However, I found that the I have vim74 instead of vim73 (`/usr/share/vim/vim74/`).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Check file `/Users/boss/.vimrc` in 6 line probably in this line configured  connection with syntax.vim from wrong pathy (for example from the old version of vim)
I suspect that the problem is caused by an update vim.

You can try update this path to `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim` or `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim` (if it variable correct defined). But pervously check that syntax definition file exists.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, after `update` OS packages, `vim73` *updated* to `vim74`.

`VIMRUNTIME` is the related *variable* for this that could be set in *$HOME/.profile* or set in */etc/profile* as permanent to the new path(*.../vim74/*) dependence on your OS distribution